# Adding Script Component to VS2015 generated package doesn't run on SQL Server 2016

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2016, script-component

We are upversioning from SQL 2012 with a BIML-generated package containing a script component. We're receiving an error that I am able to reproduce in a fresh project without BIML.

The error is:

*Failed validation and returned error code 0xC0048021.*

*The component is missing, not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The contact information for this component is "Includes and runs custom script code. For example, apply a business rule that limits the range of valid values in an "income" column or add values in two columns and calculate the average of the sum.;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;9".*

*The component metadata for "Parse PatientContacts, clsid {4F885D04-B578-47B7-94A0-DE9C7DA25EE2}" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.*

*Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ComponentVersionMismatchException: The version of Parse PatientContacts is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.  [[The version or pipeline version or both for the specified component is higher than the current version.  This package was probably created on a new version of DTS or the component than is installed on the current PC.]]
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostCheckAndPerformUpgrade(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 lPipelineVersion)*

To ensure it wasn't the BIML or VS2012, I can reproduce this error using VS2015 by:

- Created a new project in Visual Studio 2015
- Configured the TargetServerVersion to be SQL Server 2016
- Created a data flow with a Script Component between my Data Source and -Destination
- Saved and built the project. Picked up the .ispac file from the bin folder
- Deployed the Project on my SQL Server 2016 instance using SSMS 17
- Executed the package configuring the Environment to the correct values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.